# What is פורגן? Why should there be a chashash?

Tags: words, tzitzis

[This website](http://www.techeiles-chabura.com) discusses the hiddurim of the tzitzit it sells. One of the hiddurim it discusses is that the strings are "ללא חשש "פורגן, without a chashash (fear) of "פורגן." I have consulted my dictionaries and Google Translate, but I cannot find a definition for פורגן. What is it and why is there a chashash associated with it?

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47435_71.pdf) says that they are strings opposite of lishmah, meaning they are strings that have already been spun and there might be a issue that they were not watched during the entire spinning process.

I e-mailed the company concerning what the word meant and here's the reply:

> It's Yiddish. It refers to the wool being pre spun into strands. Some consider it to be tviyah which would need to be lishma.

Comment: I don't think that's what it says there. It says since they "come apart" before being spun Lishmah, their current state isn't considered spun. I don't know what the פורגן state is, but it's not just a concern of supervision.